# Getting application dependencies for creating snap package

Tags: dependencies, packaging, snap, qt5

I intended to create universal installer for distributing my qt5-based application on different Linux distributions. Currently I support building installation .deb packages than can be used on Ubuntu systems. But they can not be installed on plenty of Linux systems (e. g. RPM-based systems).

But recently snap packages support for all major Linuxes has been announced. I've tried some snapcraft examples and everything was good. But when I try to make snap packge for own qt-based application, snapcraft wizard can`t find all dependencies for it. Can someone explain me how does snapcraft investigate and gather all required dependencies for provided files?

What is the best way to include distribution-specific files (e. g. libraries like libicudata.so.55) to run my application as a portable software on different Linux distributions?

Answer (score 0):

Add all the packages whose contents you want shipped as part of your snap in `stage-packages:`. This will only work for packages shipped in Ubuntu (for now).

Take a look at https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/tree/master/gitter-im for an app, which extracts and ships general binaries in the snap.

Comment: That's nice. But what if I have some dependencies that aren't included into target Linux distribution?

Comment: No problem. It'll use what your apt sources give you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: If you have configured `apt` locally, so that it downloads the package you need, `snapcraft` will make use of it.

Comment: How can I configure apt, so that it downloads the package intended for another Linux distribution?

Comment: Ok, in that case, that won't work. You'll have to either 1) build from source or 2) bundle the binary. https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/tree/master/gitter-im could be an example for the latter.